# Getting /usr partition bigger to upgrade Ubuntu version

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

I have a double boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 on one partition and Windows on the other:

```
$ df
File system    1K-blocchi     Usati Disponib. Uso% Montato su
udev              4013652         0   4013652   0% /dev
tmpfs              807040     17864    789176   3% /run
/dev/sda8        19091584  13206476   4892240  73% /
tmpfs             4035196     68704   3966492   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             4035196         0   4035196   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1          507904     66516    441388  14% /boot/efi
/dev/sda9       440480096 301932456 116149432  73% /home
tmpfs              807040       148    806892   1% /run/user/1000
```

When I try to upgrade my Linux version, I receive the following message:

```
The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 6.661 M free space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 2.198 M of disk space on '/'.
```

This is a screenshot from Gparted: 
[image]
I need more `/` space, so I would like to expand my partition (there is no alternative), and I am using Gparted to do so (with appropriate backup tools). However, before I play with the partitions, I would like to know an opinion from any experts about which ones I should shrink and which ones whould I get bigger.

Comment: Do you mean `/home` partition, when you write '/usr` partition? Or do you mean the root partition `/`? Anyway, we would need a view of the whole partition table (output of `parted` or `gparted` in order to give good advice.

Comment: @sudodus I have edited the question to reflect the actual error message that I receive.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :-) I asked for a view of the whole partition table in order to know the location of the partitions. You can only 'steal' drive space from the surrounding partitions, and it is easier from the one behind, but the location is not always according to the numbers of the partitions. So if `/dev/sda9` is behind `/dev/sda8` according to the graphical interface of `gparted`, fine, then you can shrink `/dev/sda9`, move it so that there will be unallocated space in front of it, and then expand `/dev/sda8` to use that unallocated space.

Comment: But beware, editing partitions is risky. It is very important to **backup everything that you cannot afford to lose** before you start editing.

Comment: "(there is no alternative)" Sorry? There are several methods. 1: You only need 2.2Gb. Out of the currently used 13Gb: check /var/log/ and remove all that have a digit in the name. Then empty the biggest one using `> /var/log/{logile}`. Scan your system for the largest personal file in / but outside of /home/ and temp. move it to /home. Should be possible to upgrade if you find a 2.3+ Gb

Comment: 2. you can use a symlink. Move files (preserve permissions) to /home/{dir} and create a symlink /{dir} to /home/{dir}. Move it back when done. A bit more dangerous but not as dangerous as moving partitions :) Create backups whatever you decide to do. Shrinking and enlarging partitions is doable but takes a long long time when partitions are full(ish).

Comment: @sudodus, if it helps, I have added a screenshot from Gparted.

Comment: @Rinzwind, just to be sure, we are talking about `sda8`, correct?

Comment: yes sda8. so not /home/ :)

Comment: 1. You can try to remove files that are not necessary, maybe it will release enough free space according to Rinzwind; 2. According to the screenshot of `gparted` you can shrink the big `/dev/sda9`, move it so that there will be unallocated space in front of it, and then expand `/dev/sda8` to use that unallocated space. -- Make sure there is a sufficient backup and good luck :-)

Comment: The problem with @Rinzwind suggestion is that, I have tried already to delete files in `/`, and it was not enough. There are other large (~Gb) directories, e.g. `/usr/share`, but I am not sure they can be deleted...

Comment: don't delete them. you can empty /var/log/ but I suggested to move some large personal files over to /home/ if  there are any. Another method would be to create /home/usr/share/, move /usr/share/ to /home/usr/share and then symlink /usr/share/ to /home/usr/share. Plenty of options besides making / larger :)

Comment: So, I would move the directory and then `ln -s /home/usr/share /usr/share/`, correct? Do I still need to backup before doing this?

Comment: @Rinzwind, if you can answer. How do I link a directory that I just moved? Also, backup or not backup?